# Return table with rows where certain column is blank

Tags: powerbi, dax

I thinks this is a very easy to answer question ,but I cant figure it out and im very beginner in DAX.

I have this sample data set:
[image]

I want to return a Table in powerbi with only the rows where job is blank. So it would look like this:
[image]

How to do this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you mentioned DAX, you may use this expression to return a Table with only the rows, where job is blank:

```
FILTER('Table','Table'[job] = BLANK())
```

But I guess, it make sense for you only inside the measures, you want to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the button in the title for `job` column and uncheck all values, except `(Blank)`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is also usefull, but I meant the DAX query :)